# Buy X Pay for Y Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, price, discount

I have to write "Buy X Pay for Y" algorithm.
Request that comes to my endpoint is list of Articles

```
public class Article
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

payFor variable comes from db and is defined by package discount id

Here's my algorithm that I wrote so far

```
if (purchasedQuantity >= minPurchaseQuantity)
{
    var c = 0;
    foreach (var article in articlesForPackage.OrderByDescending(a => a.UnitPrice))
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= article.Quantity; i++)
        {
            c++;

            if (c > payFor)
            {
                c = 0;

                result.Add(new Discount
                {
                    Value = article.UnitPrice
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this algorithm does not work in some cases.

When the package discount is defined buy 3 and pay for 2 it works, but if buy 3 pay for one doesn't work.
Could somebody help me?

This is how the algorithm should work:
We have 3 articles
1 Art1 - 20$
2 Art2 - 30$
3 Art3 - 40$

If minPurchaseQuantity is 3 and payFor is 2 it means that cost of Art1 should be added to result list (because it is the cheapest one)

If minPurchaseQuantity is 3 and payFor is 1 it means that cost of Art2 and Art1 should be added to result list (Now only the Art2 is adding)

Comment: Could you describe what is `"Buy X Pay for Y" algorithm` ?

Comment: `TotalPrice = Price * (PayFor * Quantity / BuyX + Quantity % BuyX)` - Is this really what you want to implement?

Comment: The pricing is buy 3 and pay for 2. The prices of the 6 things I buy are $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6. What should i pay? The most common interpretation (in stores) is that the discount would be $1 and $4. Is that your interpretation? Also, what should I pay if I buy only 5 of them (i.e. not the $6 one)?

Comment: Yes it is my interpretation. If you buy only 5 Discount only for $1 should be created

Comment: Cool, so step one is batching. You need to batch your items (price descending) in batches of 3. https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ has a `Batch` which does that. Then, for each batch, skip 2 (the number of ones you pay for). The rest of items in that batch are free. Repeat for each batch.

Comment: `If you buy only 5 Discount only for $1 should be created` I am going to assume you made a typo, and meant to say a discount of $3 (if buying items for $1 $2 $3 $4 $5)?

Comment: If the rule was buy 5 pay for 3, what should I pay if I buy 4 items of $1 $2 $3 $4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the main issue is, that you reset `c` as soon as it gets larger than `payFor`. This works as long as `minPurchaseQuantity-payFor=1`, but in other cases it won't.

While it's not as easy as the solution I presented in my first answer, I think the actual algorithm can be implemented more concisely. The following code first batches the items in groups eligible for discount. For each of the batches it then skips as many as `payFor` items and calculates the discount from the rest

```
// first batch the items in batches eligible for discount (e.g. batches of three in take 3, pay for x)
var batchedItems = BatchItemsEligibleForDiscount(items, minPurchaseQuantity);
var discounts = batchedItems.Select(batch => batch.Skip(payFor)) 
                            .SelectMany(batch => batch) // flatten nested IEnumerable to an IEnumerable<Artible>
                            .Select(article => new Discount() { Value = article.UnitPrice });
```

The `BatchItemsEligibleForDiscount` gets the batches that are eligible for discount (i.e. have 3 items each if it's *"take 3, pay for X"*. Articles with a `Quantity>1` are *"exploded"*, i.e. if the quantity is 3, 3 distinct objects are created.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Article>> BatchItemsEligibleForDiscount(items, minPurchaseQuantity)
{
    return items.OrderByDescending(article => article.UnitPrice)
                .Select(article => Enumerable.Range(1, article.Quantity).Select(n => new Article() { Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = article.UnitPrice })) // "explode" articles 
                .SelectMany(item => item) // flatten to an IEnumerable<Article>
                .Select((article, index) => new { article, index })
                .GroupBy(x => x.index / minPurchaseQuantity)
                .Where(group => group.Count() == minPurchaseQuantity) // only take batches elegible for discount
                .Select(group => group.Select(x => x.article));
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/orbBJj) for a demonstration.

**OLD ANSWER**

Calculating the discount is way easier. You can calculate the number of bundles elegible for discount (if its take 3, pay for 2 and 8 items, you have two whole bundles of 3 items each). By calculating the difference between the items to take and the items to pay and multiplying it with the number of bundles and the price per item, you can calculate the discount

```
var numberOfDiscountableBundles = article.Quantity / amountOfItemsElegibleForDiscount; 
var discount = numberOfDiscountableBundles * (amountOfItemsElegibleForDiscount - payFor) * article.UnitPrice;
```

**Example:** Take 3, pay for 1 with 8 items:

```
numberOfDiscountableBundles = 8 / 3 = 2 (integer division!)
discount = 2 * (3 - 1) * p = 2 * 2 * p = 4 * p
```

It's two discounted bundles of three items each (six items). Four of those items are **not** payed for (only one per bundle), hence the total price is discounted by four times the price of a unit.

You could encapsule this in a method

```
Discount CalculateDiscountForArticle(Article article, int amountOfItemsElegibleForDiscount, int payFor)
{
    var numberOfDiscountableBundles = article.Quantity / amountOfItemsElegibleForDiscount; 
    var discount = numberOfDiscountableBundles * (amountOfItemsElegibleForDiscount - payFor) * article.UnitPrice;

    return new Discount
               {
                   Value = discount
               };
}
```

And your original function gets as easy as

```
var discounts = articlesForPackage.OrderByDescending(a => a.UnitPrice)
                                  .Select(a => CalculateDiscountForArticle(a, amountOfItemsElegibleForDiscount, payFor));
```

**EDIT TO OLD ANSWER**

If the discount is granted only once per customer and article, the calculation is a bit different

```
double discount = 0;
if(article.Quantity >= amountOfItemsElegibleForDiscount)
{
    var discount = (amountOfItemsElegibleForDiscount - payFor) * article.UnitPrice;
}
```

Comment: How do you handle `Buy 3, pay for 1` when client picks `2` or `5` or any `3*n+2` products?

Comment: @Rafalon Depends on your requirements. How do **you need it** to be handled? If the discount is applied for each group of 3 items, my first solution applies. If it's granted only once see my edit.

Comment: Added an example to my answer.

Comment: Sorry I try to understand your answer but I can't I have three articles(Art1 - 1$, Art2 - 2$, Art3 - 3$) and should I pay only for 1(2 should I get free) So in this case 2 Discounts should be created (for 1$ and $2).  You answer gives me three discounts  with 2 as a Value. What shoiuld I do with those values?

Comment: @MichałMatuszek Seems as if I misunderstood your requirements. I thought that you were talking about buy 3 items (of the same type) and pay just 2.

Comment: @MichałMatuszek I'll try to edit my answer accordingly later.

Comment: @PaulKertscher nope, You can mix them together. So for example: you can buy 1$ x 2 and $2 x 1. In this case discount also should be calculated (for 1$ x 1)

Comment: @PaulKertscher Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189263/discussion-between-paul-kertscher-and-michal-matuszek).

Comment: My comment was precisely more about the fact that we didn't really have OP requirements, and so I was amazed as to how you came with an answer :)

Comment: @Rafalon Well, obviously I *thought* that I did understand OPs requirements enough ;)

Comment: @MichałMatuszek please see my edit. I think now I have reflected your requirements in my code.